# Android pass data back to calling class

Tags: android, class

I'm getting confused with an Android app I'm building it as it's my first one. I have two classes, my first one is called "Options" which calls the second class "NetworkConnection" which in turn checks to see if there is a network connection available, if there is I could like to pass back a "1" or if there isn't then pass back a "0". I'm doing it this was as I would like to use "NetworkConnection" within several other classes and it seems like the best way to do it. Would someone either point me to a simple example of just add a couple of lines of code to the below, cheeky I know but I can't work it out, it's not like normal Java?! Many thanks :)

public class Options extends Activity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
            NetworkConection nc = new NetworkConection();

    }
```

}

//Network connection class

public class NetworkConnection extends Activity {

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myClickHandler(null);
}

public void myClickHandler(View view ) {

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        //pass back the value of 1
    } else {
       //pass back the value of 0 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of confused to the logic you're using. Why are you using an Activity in the second class if you just want to check connection?

Also why return 0 and 1? Why not return a boolean true or false?

So I think this is what you want?

```
public class Options extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.options);
        NetworkConection nc = new NetworkConection();
        boolean networkAvail = nc.isNetworkConnAvail(); 

    }
}
```

So second class you want to check if connection available. So
I created a public method so you can call in the options class.

```
public class NetworkConnection{

    public boolean isNetworkConnAvail() {

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null)
            return networkInfo.isConnected();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution although you could just return the condition rather than evaluate it and then return true or false.

Comment: Yeah good point. I wasn't really thinking about that as I was just using the code he provided. I'll fix that now. Thanks Luke :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you extending Activity? Are you showing a new view whilst it tests?
If you are then you need to use startActivityForResult and the use setResult to return the result

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Answer (score 0):

To launch an activity, you have to do it like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent (Options.this, NetworkConnection.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, NETWORK_CONNECTION);
```

The code above means you want to start an activity. [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) means you expect something when the new one will be close and go back to the first (Options, in your case).
The result can be catch in the [`OnActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) (in Options) with the code NETWORK_CONNECTION (a global var you will create in Options).

When you close your NetworkConnection activity, just do this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("myresult", thevalueyouwant);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

In that way, you'll be able to read the value of "myresult" in the onActivityResult in the Options activity.

My answer is not complete, but you have to read more about these methods to succeed ;)

Comment: Also, read the others comments, they can be right. Maybe you don't need to make NetworkConnexion extends Activity.